# What are the differences between different kinds of datums (datum, datumhash, inlineDatum, inlineDatumHash)?

Tags: utxo, datum, inline-datum, datum-hash

I sent some ADA to a smart contract address with the non inline datum of "1234" and when i queried the utxo with cardano-cli, I got this result.

```
"603ca96747bd39152a36d185662a6092f68d7f1c97dd65de81484c72168da3e2#0": {
    "address": "addr_test1wzhqvrgumuy3jc44w763cudwyass0rzm2rthuve9vy5k7gggadmgm",
    "datum": null,
    "datumhash": "b2d7e9699dc52c42ab1aa0f28e4d9d28e0f6f7d780054b024722b87611c13de8",
    "inlineDatum": null,
    "referenceScript": null,
    "value": {
        "lovelace": 10000000
    }
}
```

And when I sent the same some ADA with the inline datum of "1234" I got this result.

```
"d1dbd36e840f0005d53c976f8426134b6378b5eb40e04948c537f238a9d10a98#0": {
    "address": "addr_test1wzhqvrgumuy3jc44w763cudwyass0rzm2rthuve9vy5k7gggadmgm",
    "datum": null,
    "inlineDatum": {
        "bytes": "1234"
    },
    "inlineDatumhash": "b2d7e9699dc52c42ab1aa0f28e4d9d28e0f6f7d780054b024722b87611c13de8",
    "referenceScript": null,
    "value": {
        "lovelace": 10000000
    }
}
```

I have some understanding of inlinedatum and datumhash but what are those datum and inlnedatumhash are for?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `datum` is ever used, it should probably be removed from this output. `inlineDatumHash` is probably just for convenience so you can know the hash of the inline datum, it's not needed for using the inline datum as witness.